# AsyncTask doesn't execute

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I'm trying to change my old app but now is not going through AsyncTask. I'm debugging but the thread stuck in the task.

```
RevisarTask rt = (RevisarTask) new RevisarTask().execute(usuario, password, eventoId, "","http://server:8988");
            try {
                while(rt.getStatus().name().equals("RUNNING")){
                    System.out.println("running");
                }
                retorno = rt.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, e);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, e);
            }
```

This is the task but never goes through the code.

```
public class RevisarTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

 protected String doInBackground(String... verification) {
        String message = RevisarCodigoWS.revisar(verification[0], verification[1], verification[2],verification[3],verification[4]);
         if(message==null){
            message ="Data not valid";
         }else {
             if (message.indexOf("failed to connect") >= 0 && !"".equals(verification[3])) {
                 SessionTickets.addValidationCache(verification[3]);
             }
         }
    return message;
 }


}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "Thread stuck in task"? Where exactly it is stuck?

Comment: Stuck in (RevisarTask) new RevisarTask().execute

Comment: Doesn't execute or go through "RevisarTask"

Comment: @Antoniomc tell me first, why you typecast RevisarTask class